# make call to external threaded library be single threaded inside omp parallel region

Tags: multithreading, performance, optimization, parallel-processing, openmp

I am making a nested parallelism inside a C++ code.

I am parallelizing a for-loop with `#omp parallel for`, and inside the for-loop I have a call to an external library. That is, each iteration of the for-loop calls the external library once.

The call is to the `gemm()` function from BLAS.

I want this call to be issued using 1 thread only. That is, I DO NOT want each thread from the pool of workers to issue calls to `gemm()` using `OMP_NUM_THREADS` threads as resources. This would create a factor of `OMP_NUM_THREADS` more threads than the number of cores I have.

From the manual of `cray-libsci`, I read (I am using the cray compiler):

```
                  Table 2. Compiler‐specific Libraries
 ‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐
 Compiler Default Link         To switch libraries, specify
 ‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐
 CCE      to serial non‐       ‐homp (fortran) or ‐fopenmp
          threaded libs        (C/C++) (for openmp threaded libs)
```

All good, I could remove `-fopemp` flag from the compilation and the calls which use cray-libsci are single-threaded.

The problem is that apart from BLAS, I am using another external library called `shtns` which is threaded and has to be called with `OMP_NUM_THREADS`, thus I need the `-fopenmp` flag to be present at compilation time.

The calls to `shtns` happen outside the `#omp parallel for` region.

Is there a way to make the calls to `gemm()` single threaded inside the `#omp parallel for`?

Thank you!

Comment: Normally, a call to `omp_set_nested(0)` in your code will further disable nested parallelism. That is, if a parallel region is encountered within an other parallel region, the OpenMP runtime won't start additional threads.

Comment: Not all BLAS libraries use OpenMP internally. There is generally a function to set the number of threads of the BLAS library (eg. in the MKL).